# Add additional information between appended write.table outputs in R

Tags: r, write.table

I am trying to output a series of tables to a CSV file using the `append=TRUE` argument of the `write.table` function. However I would like to add additional information between the tables (eg. table captions).

I'm very new to R and don't know how to use loops/define functions, etc. so do everything line by line, so would appreciate solutions to be in a similar simple format so that I am able to manipulate the code for other uses later.

My current code is:

```
table1 <- aggregate(myData[,7:11],by=list(myData$Variable1), min)
table2 <- aggregate(myData[,7:11],by=list(myData$Variable1), median)
table3 <- aggregate(myData[,7:11],by=list(myData$Variable1), max)
write.table(table1, file="myDataTables.csv", append = FALSE, sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
write.table(table2, file="myDataTables.csv", append = TRUE, sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
write.table(table3, file="myDataTables.csv", append = TRUE, sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
```

My csv file then comes out like this:

```
table 1 column names
table 1 data (10 rows)
table 2 column names
table 2 data (10 rows)
table 3 column names
table 3 data (10 rows)
```

What I'd like it to look like (including the blank rows) is:

```
Table 1 caption (eg. "Table 1: Table name")
table 1 column names
table 1 data (10 rows)

Table 2 caption (eg. "Table 2: Table name")
table 2 column names
table 2 data (10 rows)

Table 3 caption (eg. "Table 3: Table name")
table 3 column names
table 3 data (10 rows)
```

When I was sending output to .txt files, I used the cat function to add in captions and blank lines as in the following:

```
out<-capture.output(table1)
cat("Table 1: Table Name","",out,"","",file="myDataTables.txt",sep="\n",append=TRUE)
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this when writing CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution, which is more or less the code you included in your question.

```
co2_mins <- aggregate(. ~ Plant, CO2, min)
co2_medians <- aggregate(. ~ Plant, CO2, median)
co2_maxs <- aggregate(. ~ Plant, CO2, max)

out_file <- "myDataTables.csv"
sep <- ","
cat("Table 1: CO2 minima by plant\n", file = out_file)
write.table(co2_mins, out_file, append = TRUE, sep = sep)
cat("\nTable 2: CO2 medians by plant\n", file = out_file, append = TRUE)
write.table(co2_mins, out_file, append = TRUE, sep = sep)
cat("\nTable 3: CO2 maxima by plant\n", file = out_file, append = TRUE)
write.table(co2_mins, out_file, append = TRUE, sep = sep)
```

Only slightly fancier is to use a `for` loop.  This is more easily generalisable, because you can add or remove new summary statistics with ease.  It's also less prone to mistakes, but you aren't copying and pasting code several times.  (This follows the principle of [*don't repeat yourself*](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself).)

```
fns <- list(minima = min, medians = median, maxima = max)
for(i in seq_along(fns))
{
  summary_stats <- aggregate(. ~ Plant, CO2, fns[[i]])
  cat(
    if(i > 1) "\n",
    "Table ", i, ": CO2 ", names(fns)[i], " by plant\n", 
    file = out_file, 
    sep = "",
    append = i > 1
  )
  write.table(
    summary_stats, 
    out_file, 
    append = TRUE, 
    sep = ","
  )
}
```

---

I should probably point out that what you want is a bit weird.  CSV files are great for storing data, but not for reading by humans. Having this situation of multiple CSV files plus captions for human reading makes it difficult to to use programmatically, so now you have a file that is hard to read and bad for data storage.

It's better to keep your data stored in individual CSV files, and then use the `knitr` package to autogenerate a report from your data.

Comment: Thanks, for people who use R for most of their data analysis, I can understand it seems weird! But currently my R skills only extend to basic analysis of data - so I use it to read in excel data, do descriptive and inferential stats then export the data back into excel to create graphs for displaying the results and for other people in my team who don't do programming to see the data/analysis. (I know you can produce a multitude of plots in R, but learning how to make/customise them to match our branded Excel chart templates is too steep a learning curve for me right now.)

Comment: And of course if I could understand 'for' loops I would use them, but none of the various documentation, you tube videos or coursera courses I have looked at have been able to sufficiently explain them to me in a way that I actually understand how to use them for the purposes I need them. I get the concept at a basic level, and can  write simple/useless loops, I just can't translate it to my own work - I have no programming background and don't fully understand most of the functions I'm using. One day!

Comment: *Hands on programming with R* http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028574.do is the gentlest book on R I know.  It's written for people who have zero programming experience, and has a step-by-step section on for loops.

Comment: And don't worry about not getting stuff.  Every programmer has a few years where everything is new and difficult.  Eventually things will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this solution is working in your particular example, but it seems to work pretty wellinmy case (except from outputing some warning messsages for some events):

Lets say you have wrapped all your tables into a list, and then you have a "for loop" to append them in a single csv file. Then you may use that, to produce an "empty row", into each written csv table:

```
list_tables 
[[1]]
Table1 
[[2]]
Table2
[[3]]
Table3
[[4]]
Table4

 write.table( rbind(list_tables[[i]], ""), path-filename, append=T, ....)
```